# Where are the iPad Mini and iPad 4th-generation tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed [a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71672/what-is-the-net-weight-and-outside-size-of-the-ipad-mini-box-when-new) specific to the iPad Mini had been tagged as [ipad-3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-3). While retagging I noticed there don't seem to be tags for the newest (4th-generation) iPad or the iPad Mini.

Someone should probably create these (I don't believe I have the rep). Further, since it appears the iPads won't bear numbers in their trade names the way iPhones do, is it effective / worthwhile to continue making separate *ipad-4, ipad-5, ipad-mini-2, etc.* tags for each, or should we treat them more like Macs, which don't receive a separate tag-per-generation?

Answer (score 1):

I've created an [ipad-mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-mini) tag and will watch it so see things are going smoothly. If you want to make a new question (or an edit here) linking to some questions that need [ipad-4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-4) I'll gladly do the same.

As to the utility of generational tags, we have a chat room to bang out ideas and can always schedule a meeting if people wish. Anyone can also ask here to form community consensus about merging existing tags / make the case for or against having separate tags for each generation.

In general, tagging things with iPad (and only iPad) lets people find and answer questions and the iPad 4 LTE / AT&T sub model specifics almost always are discoverable and searchable via the text of the question or the presence of auxiliary tags like [cellular-data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-data) or [lte](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lte) in conjunction with the [ipad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad).

Comment: We do need to flesh this out as a group, but IMO there should be an [tag:iPad] tag and all generations and variations should be a synonym.

Comment: I totally agree with @JasonSalaz here - I don't see any need to have a new iMac tag despite the radical changes that product line has gone through since questions can and do list the generation or other identifying criteria. When things are new, the tendancy seems to be to focus on that which can be measured and classified - but over time, the general tags seem to be of the most use to the community.